# How resize W10 sound speaker window?

Tags: windows-10

When I click on my volume icon in the tray
[image]
it opens full screen. There is no context menu options or system menu (Alt+spacebar). How can I resize this screen?
[image]

Comment: It's got an up arrow, ^ top right… what's that do?

Comment: That opens the select playback service dropdown to select between you speaker and any headset installed...

Comment: Its not supposed to fill the screen like this. Do you have software installed that will resize/move windows automatically? For example software to make all apps full-screen, or a align on a grid, etc?

Comment: Indeed they are not! Fences or FancyZones or something? No.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the machine and it went away. I'll see if it comes back.